# How this command find a file in Rpm package

Tags: linux, shell, command, find, rpm

I have given command which will find a particular file named /etc/limits in one of rpm package insatlled but when run on my system getting error not the desired result. Below is the command

```
find . -name '*.rpm' | while read A; do $RPM -qpl $A | grep etc/limits; \
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo $A; fi; done
/etc/limits
```

When I run this command getting below error

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `/etc/limits'
```

Could anybody tell me what is going wrong here?

Comment: 1. You say "rpm package installed" but you use the `-p` flag which means you are searching RPMs in the directory tree (from `.`) but not the installed RPMs.
2. To search the *installed* RPMs, it is much easier to simply do `rpm -q --whatprovides /etc/limits`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's evident that your `while` loop takes input from `find` so you don't need `/etc/limits` after `done` in your script.  Saying:

```
find . -name '*.rpm' | while read A; do
  $RPM -qpl $A | grep /etc/limits;
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo $A; fi;
done
```

should work.  If you wanted to make the `while` loop read from a file you'd have said:

```
while read A; do ... done < /path/to/input/file
```

Comment: Thanks @devnull but whenever I give this command its tells me "bash: -qpl: command not found " but qpl is very working on my machine

Comment: I thought that you have a variable `RPM` in your script that is defined as `RPM=rpm`.  If that is not the case, then instead of `$RPM` say `rpm`.

Comment: It is working now but still I can't narrow down my search ,using /path/to/input/file after done required full path or /etc/limit is enough??

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar I'm not sure what you're asking but use either of two approaches.  Don't pipe to `while` and make it read from a file at the same time.

Comment: this is where command is being used successfully but for its me its not working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18228503/how-yocto-generating-these-etc-limits-files/18253748#18253748

Comment: Try: `find . -name *.rpm | while read A; do rpm -qpl $A | grep -q /etc/limits && echo $A; done`  Make sure that you have the desired rpms in the current directory.